# Automate update two different SP list automatically after submitting infoPath form

Tags: 2013, list, infopath, infopath-form

I have InfoPath 2013 form which have 8 different views and different SharePoint lists: List A (Pulling Data) & List B (Submit Data).

Right now I am entering data manually in List A. I wanted to automated if user come and Enter the Unique ID which is not have record stored in List A and user enter the details and submit the form then it should be entry Updated in List & List B in Proper format.

If you have any reference URL please share. it would be appreciated.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with infopath,but same could be achieved by adding simple web part.After editing page in List B-->Add web part-->categories-->List A.So activities that would happen in list A would be reflecting in List B also.

Comment: Hi @user85213, Actually the fields are different different in List A & List B .

Comment: In that case you can call get api on list A,then in success part of it,perform insert/update operation in list B i.e. you may perform crud operation.refrence link: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/990131/CRUD-Operation-to-List-Using-SharePoint-Rest-API

Comment: Hey Many Thanks.

Comment: Happy to help:) If it found relevant for you then please mark it as answer and upvote it so that it can help someone who is looking for same.

Comment: Yup im checking now. im not sure exactly it working or not. once i confirm i will mark as Answer.

Comment: List A (have some data) & List B (Submit data by user). wanted to do automate process. i have designed infopath form and there is field (APP ID) user select App ID and Data will be pulled from List A and display in multi line text box. facing problem is if user come with new APP ID and Data not available in List A. but form allow to submit the data. List B information updated but how we can automate if it is new APP ID then how Data updated after submiting form. because user came next time and select that APP ID then Information should be available.